# Cannot edit the context menu in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, context-menu

I cannot remove items from the context menu. I have followed every step in [How To Geek guide](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/how-to-clean-up-your-messy-windows-context-menu/) to disable options in the context menu but NOTHING works.

Deleting the registery entry for the context menu option does not work.

Disabling the context menu option through CCleaner does not work.

I have rebooted a couple of times. Nothing works. The ONLY time something MIGHT work is if I disable it using MenuMaid, which does not give access to all context menu options.

Comment: http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shell_menu_view.html

Comment: Also http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html